# Global Framework (Bootstrap, Foundation ...) JS Detection for Smartphones

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, zurb-foundation, detection, smartphone

I have come across this a couple of times. Sometimes there is a need to figure out if your chosen framework like Foundation or Bootstrap has detected the actual device to be a smartphone or not. While you could always go for window.width() it is safer and more reliable to check whether or not your framework really displays smartphone content or not (especially if you change your breakpoints in SASS and do not want to change JS manually).

To do so I have figured out the best way to do this is to check the css of a given framework class that is used in a header / footer and so is being used in every template globally.

This is the jQuery js that checks if foundation (foundation.zurb.com) has detected a smartphone every time the window is resized:

```
var smartPhone;
jQuery(window).bind('resizeEnd', function () {
   if ($(".show-for-small-only").css("display") == "block") {
       smartPhone = 1;
   }
   else {
       smartPhone = 0;
   }
});
```

Hope it helps. This code can be edited to work for every framework that does add some CSS to a class on smartphones. So I could not think of one that this does not work for. Have fun!

Additionally you could use it to detect tablets, netbooks and so on. Please, be so kind and post your code if you did this, because it can be a bit complicated to sort out that code for every framework. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap code:

```
var smartPhone;
jQuery(window).bind('resizeEnd', function () {
   if ($(".visible-xs").css("display") == "block") {
       smartPhone = 1;
   }
   else {
       smartPhone = 0;
   }
});
```